# How to project picture onto hair particles?

Tags: particles, hair

Here I have a basic plane with hair particles (just for example) [image]

And here is something i want ,this black line, it should be visible when looking from angle in case when there is more particles on image up hair it’s too infrequent to be visible.

[image]

How can I do this? Also I would want to be able to move object and not change pattern while doing so.
This line is just an example I would like to add something different if this is even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an image texture to hair-emitter-object and use object-coordinates. Then change the rotation (location and size if needed) of texture with mapping node to get the required result (In this example, for side projection, x or y = 90). [image]

Comment: (Or any other object's  coordinates, if you want to get a bit fancier)

Comment: Thanks! This works, but for exactly what I wanted it'll be a bit complicated but is doable.